# PSU connector correct size for this motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

The ATX motherboard I am looking at requires a PSU connector of size:

```
24+8
```

The PSU has connectors as such:

```
Main connector: 20+4 pin
CPU 12V connector: 8pin
```

I am assuming the `24` here equates to the `20+4 pin` and the `8` here is the same as the `8pin` CPU 12V?

The PSU: http://item.jd.com/818073.html (http://www.corsair.com/en/vs-seriestm-vs650-650-watt-power-supply)

The motherboard: http://item.jd.com/1135550.html (http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4995#ov)

Comment: Its called a PSU, and yup, those should work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes it will work.

**Long answer:**

The `24+8` is just as you say the `20+4 pin` ATX connector and the `8 pin` CPU connector (also known as an EPS connector).

For the sake of completeness, I will refer to [this site](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html) and [this guide](http://www.buildcomputers.net/power-supply-connectors.html), which both have lots of pictures, so you can confirm yourself that you are indeed on the right track.

Hopefully this will also provide a reference for people who find this question by searching.